MODULE NOT FOUND
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import { getKeypairFromEnvironment } from '@solana-developers/helpers';


const keypair = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");
console.log("Public Key:", keypair.publicKey.toString());
console.log("Private Key:", keypair.secretKey);

Output Generated is
Public Key: HprpzYy7V6fJx2RCxsUUb9TtsFn8cY5mo2ZyoF2aowVi
Private Key: Uint8Array(64) [
79, 188, 209,  86, 157, 233,  52, 172,   3, 196,  91,
151, 109, 136,  74, 225, 198,  59, 224,  15, 173,  34,
85, 233,  75,  44, 212, 164, 111,  85, 175, 238, 249,
253, 161,   1, 119, 173,  57,  39, 187, 150, 243, 216,
59,  52, 191,   4,  68,  53, 177,  12, 253, 170, 172,
69,  68, 195,  85, 207, 241, 168, 202, 121
]
But when i run another program that also needs  keypair
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import {
  getExplorerLink, getKeypairFromEnvironment,
} from "@solana-developers/helpers";

import { mintTo } from "@solana/spl-token";


import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

// Our token has two decimal places
const MINOR_UNITS_PER_MAJOR_UNITS = Math.pow(10, 2);

const user = await getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");


// Subtitute in your token mint account from create-token-mint.ts
const tokenMintAccount = new PublicKey(
  "YOUR_TOKEN_MINT_ACCOUNT"
);

// Substitute in your own, or a friend's token account address, based on the previous step.
const recipientAssociatedTokenAccount = new PublicKey(
  "RECIPIENT_TOKEN_ACCOUNT"
);

const transactionSignature = await mintTo(
  connection,
  user,
  tokenMintAccount,
  recipientAssociatedTokenAccount,
  user,
  10 * MINOR_UNITS_PER_MAJOR_UNITS
);

const link = getExplorerLink("transaction", transactionSignature, "devnet");

console.log(`✅ Success! Mint Token Transaction: ${link}`);

I always get this error:
PS F:\solana\tokens-tokenprograms> npx esrun mint-tokens.ts
node:internal/modules/run_main:129
triggerUncaughtException(
^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\solana\tokens-tokenprograms\node_modules.bin\node_modules@solana-developers\helpers\dist\index.js' imported from F:\solana\tokens-tokenprograms\node_modules.bin\esrun-1716019772445.tmp.mjs
Did you mean to import "../@solana-developers/helpers/dist/index.js"?
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:265:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:933:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
url: 'file:///F:/solana/tokens-tokenprograms/node_modules/.bin/node_modules/@solana-developers/helpers/dist/index.js'
}
Node.js v20.13.1

To resolve the error you're encountering, ensure you are in the project root directory and run the following command to install the required package: :
npm i @solana-developers/helpers

This should help you resolve the ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND error and ensure that your script runs correctly.
